# Cannot `source` shc-compiled scripts

Tags: bash, binary, include

Is there any way to `source` (include) compiled script?

I use [shc](http://www.datsi.fi.upm.es/~frosal/) to compile all of my scripts and when I run them from the command line they work OK to start. But when script have to include other two scripts (`variables.sh.x` and `functions.sh.x`) it crashes and returns an error, that binary files can not be included.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

including piece of code:

```
source $(dirname $0)/variables.sh.x
source $(dirname $0)/functions.sh.x
```

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that, your `.x` files are just plain old executables, they'll behave as such. Why are you compiling anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[shc](http://www.datsi.fi.upm.es/~frosal/) does not actually compile scripts. It merely obfuscates them by encrypting and embedding them inside a C program, so it cannot improve performance. The actual shell still interprets and executes the code and is required for the script to run.

If you absolutely must use this tool to obfuscate your code, you will have to combine everything into a single file.