# unable to run shell script compiler binary which having dependency internally with another shell script

Tags: shell, binary

I have two shell scripts which have dependencies. Using `shc` compiler i created two binaries. But while running one binary, it is unable to resolve dependent binary. I am seeing below error:

```
line 1 : ???? :command not found
```

How to deal with shell scripts which have dependencies.

```
//first_shellscript.sh

#!/bin/bash

get_network_status()
{
    network_status=`ifconfig`
    if [ $network_status -eq 0 ]; then
        echo $network_status
    else
        echo "1"
    fi
} is shell script used by below shell script
```

```
//second_shellscript.sh

#!/bin/bash

source /path/first_shellscript.sh
get_network_status;
```

Comment: Please post at least the relevant portions of the shell scripts

Comment: It would be better readable if you can edit your post and include this code in it.

Comment: According to this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930065/cannot-source-shc-compiled-scripts), it cannot be done.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, write down as answer. I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: No `ifconfig` that I have ever seen will print simply `0` as its output.  I'm guessing you want something like `if ifconfig eth0 | grep -qw up; then ...` or something like that.  If you have a `/sys` filesystem, querying that is probably vastly preferable.

Comment: That is not the problem, i simply wrote some function, i had my own functionality inside it. My issue is how to call function resided in another script in this script. Because at times it is not possible to write down every thing in one script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[shc](http://www.datsi.fi.upm.es/~frosal/sources/shc.html) is not exactly a compiler but it rather encrypts and places the script within a C file.

It is not possible to use multiple scripts and `source` to work within a script that has to be "compiled" by shc. Only way out is to put everything in a single script.

Please read this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930065/cannot-source-shc-compiled-scripts)%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B) post